# can't get 0 from post request answer

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, post, request

I need to send email thanks to php script. Sript in the server, I did post request to the server, and got answer. If all is good I get 0, if I get 1, all is bad.

This is my code:

```
public class MessagePost
{
    public string to { get; set; }
    public string from { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendMessage(FEEDBACK feedbackModel)
    {
        try
        {
            string FromEmail = feedbackModel.sEmail;
            string toEmail = "zicise@mail.ru";
            string title = "Сообщение с сайта народный комунальщик от " + feedbackModel.vFIO;
            string message = feedbackModel.vMessage;

            MessagePost MP = new MessagePost();

            MP.to = toEmail;
            MP.from = FromEmail;
            MP.title = title;
            MP.message = message;

            List<MessagePost> dataMessage = new List<MessagePost>();

            dataMessage.Add(MP);

            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string json = serializer.Serialize(dataMessage);

            // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://projects.pushnovn.com/send_email/");
            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            request.Method = "POST";
            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            string postData = json;
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            // Get the request stream.
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            // Close the Stream object.
            dataStream.Close();
            // Get the response.
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            // Display the status.
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // Clean up the streams.
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();

            string convertResult = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);

            RootObject r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseFromServer);

            if (r.code == 0)
            {
                ViewBag.RedirectMessage = r.msg;
                return View("~/Views/Home/RedirectPage.cshtml");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.RedirectMessage = r.msg;
                return View("~/Views/Home/RedirectPage.cshtml");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            ViewBag.RedirectMessage = "Невозможно отправить e-mail - error: " + exc.Message;
            return View("~/Views/Home/RedirectPage.cshtml");
        }
    }
```

But I always get 1, what's wrong?

E.g. data

to: zicise@mail.ru

from: test@mail.ru

title: Test Title

message: Test message

Comment: So you're getting an unsuccessful response from the server this code is accessing?  Perhaps the answer would be in the response message?  Or in that server's logs?  It's not really clear to me what you're asking related to the code you're showing.

Comment: Your server returns a UTF16-encoded russian error-message in the "msg" attribute - maybe you should look what it says. You can decode UTF16 [here](https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter).

Answer (score 0):

Okay.So, I did it.But not good what I want. This is my code for send post query to the server:

```
public static HttpWebResponse PostMethod(string postedData, string postUrl)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postUrl);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        var bytes = encoding.GetBytes(postedData);

        //request.ContentType = "application/javascript";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        //request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        //request.ContentType = "application/json";
        //request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";

        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

        using (var newStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            newStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            newStream.Close();
        }
        return (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    }
```

And ActionResult:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendMessage(FEEDBACK feedbackModel)
    {
        MessageData msgData = new MessageData();

        msgData.to = "zicise@mail.ru";
        msgData.from = feedbackModel.sEmail;
        msgData.title = "Сообщение с сайта наркома от пользователя: " + feedbackModel.vFIO;
        msgData.message = feedbackModel.vFIO;

        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msgData);

        var response = PostMethod("to=zicise@mail.ru&from=narkom@info.by&title=Second method&message=test message", "http://projects.pushnovn.com/send_email/");
        //var response = PostMethod("to:zicise@mail.ru,from:narkom@info.by,title:Second method,message:test message", "http://projects.pushnovn.com/send_email/");
        //var response = PostMethod("{to:zicise@mail.ru,from:narkom@info.by,title:Second method,message:test message}", "http://projects.pushnovn.com/send_email/");
        //var response = PostMethod("[{to:zicise@mail.ru,from:narkom@info.by,title:Second method,message:test message}]", "http://projects.pushnovn.com/send_email/");
        //var response = PostMethod(jsonString, "http://projects.pushnovn.com/send_email/");

        if (response != null)
        {
            var strreader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
            var responseToString = strreader.ReadToEnd();

            RootObject r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseToString);

            ViewBag.RedirectMessage = r.msg;
        }

        return View("~/Views/Home/RedirectPage.cshtml");
    }
```

But this code worked only when I send data in format: `to=zicise@mail.ru&from=narkom@info.by&title=Second method&message=test message`

But I need to send data from model and get 0 answer. After that PHP script send me email with data. Anyone know, how to convert object in json format `name=value&name=value`